# NetLogo Initializing Turtles at Specific Co-Ordinates

Tags: netlogo, agent

in a NetLogo model, I have some "plant" turtles in a space. The number of which is 5, and will always be 5.

```
set-default-shape plants "plant"
create-plants 10
[
  set color green
  set size 2  
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
]
```

At the moment each of these plants randomly spawns in the world. I want to be able to set the point at which each of these plants is placed.

Something akin to:

```
setxy plant-1 25 25
setxy plant-2 25 25
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the line `setxy random-xcor random-ycor` is setting the x-coordinate and y-coordinate of the plants to random values. Note that you seem to have that line in your code twice. The first instance of it gets overwritten by the second. Anyway, you can also use `setxy` to move plants to particularly coordinates, e.g. `setxy 25 25`. However, replacing `setxy random-xcor random-ycor` with `setxy 25 25` would put *all* the plants at that location. I assume you want multiple plants in multiple specific locations. To do that, you can just ask the individual plants to move:

```
ask plant 0 [ setxy 25 25 ]
ask plant 1 [ setxy 10 40 ]
```

and so forth.